# how do I make two dictionary keys with value as list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Write1 [1.0]
Write1 [12.0]
Write1 ['C:/Users/san/Modeler/']
Write1 ['png']
Write1 ['rgb']
Write1 [True]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 ['']
Write2 [' ']
Write2 ['rgb']
Write2 [False]
```

I want to make dictioary like this 
{'Write1':[1.0,12.0,'c:/path','png','rgb',True],'Write2':[1.0,1.0,'',' ','rgb',False]}
the values inside the list comes from nuke.toNode(wNode)[eachAttrib].value()
this is what i tried to do

```
attributes=[]
wnodeData={}
for wNode in writeNodes:
    for eachAttrib in ['first','last','file','file_type','channels','use_limit']:
        wnodeData[wNode]=attributes
        attributes.append(nuke.toNode(wNode)[eachAttrib].value())
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read the above code block as a string or text file, and output the corresponding dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
text="""Write1 [1.0]
Write1 [12.0]
Write1 ['C:/Users/san/Modeler/']
Write1 ['png']
Write1 ['rgb']
Write1 [True]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 ['']
Write2 [' ']
Write2 ['rgb']
Write2 [False]"""

from ast import literal_eval

d = {}
lines = text.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    k, v = line.split(' ', 1)
    val = literal_eval(v)[0]
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(val)

print d

# {'Write1': [1.0, 12.0, 'C:/Users/san/Modeler/', 'png', 'rgb', True], 'Write2': [1.0, 1.0, '', ' ', 'rgb', False]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

s = '''Write1 [1.0]
Write1 [12.0]
Write1 ['C:/Users/san/Modeler/']
Write1 ['png']
Write1 ['rgb']
Write1 [True]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 [1.0]
Write2 ['']
Write2 [' ']
Write2 ['rgb']
Write2 [False]'''

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in s.split('\n'):
    print(line)
    key, val = line.split(' ', 1)
    d[key].append(val[1:-1])
print(d)
```

Obviously, if you've got a text file instead of a string, you'd replace the for loop with, say:

```
with open('mystuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
```

If you want to actually evaluate the values inside the brackets (so you get a float for the `1.0` instead of the string `'1.0'`, the string `'png'` instead of the string `"'png'"`, etc.), you need to know the language they're written in and parse that. It looks like they're a subset of Python, where each thing is either a single-quoted string literal with no escapes, a float literal in non-exponential format, or a boolean literal, but I wouldn't just assume that without knowing where the values come from (and I certainly wouldn't just call `eval` on them without knowing where they come from, because then someone could just stick `os.system('rm -rf /')` in the text file, and you'd evaluate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
write1 = {'write1':[1,2,3,4] }
```

should work ...

Answer (score 0):

make a defaultdict with the default value as a list and then start appending (or using other list methods).